# Is there a way to load a vector equal by size to global memory size of GPU in OpenCl?

Tags: opencl, boost-compute

My GPU has 12 GB global memory (CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE), but only 3 GB of memory which it can allocate (CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE). When I try to load a vector of size exceeding 3 GB, the program crashes. The question is, if it is possible to load a bigger vector into GPU memory to utilize it completely, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` reports 1/4 of `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE`, meaning it would only be allowed to allocate four 3GB buffers on a 12GB GPU.

However, Nvidia GPUs allow to allocate their full memory capacity in a single buffer, even though they also report to have the 1/4 limit.

Some AMD GPUs have the limit set higher, for example the Radeon VII lets you use 14/16GB for a single buffer.

The only devices I have ever seen that really inforce the 1/4 limit are Intel HD 4600 and 5500, so older Intel integrated GPUs. If you go above 1/4 in buffer size there, the `cl::Buffer` constructor throws error `-61`.

In case you are stuck with the 1/4 memory limit on your device, split your large 12GB buffer in 4 smaller 3GB buffers (for example one vector for x, y, z, w components of the vector each). If you use Windows, note that you might only be able to use ~11.5GB in total as some VRAM is reserved for the operating system.

---

I think your issue might not be `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` though, but 32-bit integer overflow for the array size above 4GB. Use the `uint64_t` data type to set the array size instead.

---

You might also be interested in this lightweight [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper) for C++. There, the length of vectors always is in 64-bit integer, and it automatically keeps track on how much memory you use in total on each device, telling you if you allocate too much. It also catches that `-61` error on Intel iGPUs and tells you the maximum allowed buffer size then.